# Why does typeof return "string1" or "number1"

Tags: javascript

I came across with strange behavior of typeof operator, and I did not find anything, wherever described such behavior.

```
typeof ([(0==0)+(0==0)]+[0])+((0==0)<<0) // "string1"

typeof (0^[(0==0)+(0==0)]+[0])+((0==0)<<0) // "number1"

typeof (0>>(0==0))+([0]+[(0==0)+(0==0)]^0) // "number2"
```

Comment: Because `((0==0)<<0)` is 1

Comment: `typeof` has the same level of precedence as `+` and since both are right-to-left associative, `typeof X` is executed first. Or something like that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: @megawac Yes you're right! I have not noticed that the parentheses do not mutch.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you. Because of tiredness, I didn't notice the mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing two operations in series:

```
typeof ([(0==0)+(0==0)]+[0])   +   ((0==0)<<0)

"string" + ((0==0)<<0)

"string" + 1

"string1"
```

same for all the others.

Answer (score 3):

More or less:

```
  typeof ([(0==0)+(0==0)]+[0])+((0==0)<<0)
= typeof ([   1  +  1   ]+[0])+(1<<0)
= typeof (     [2]       +[0])+(1)
= typeof ("20")               + 1
= "string"                    + 1
= "string1"
```

The part where two arrays get concatenated (third line) works because when `+` expression is evaluated, arrays are coerced into numbers (using [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)).

The right part of the expression works because `0==0` is `true`, and `true` coerces to `1` number (as seen in [9.3 of ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)).